# 2023 Moderator Election Announcement

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

SE friends,

It is, I regret to share, time for me to step down as mod. I had hoped to be a mod for longer—and a more active one!—but a recent promotion has severely impacted the time I once spent here on Music.SE. Coupled with Stack Exchange’s actions, both recent and less so, I have decided it is time I focus my skills elsewhere. I will still be present, and lucky as ever to learn from all of your expertise, but my time and contributions will be far more limited.

Stack Exchange wisely chose to wait until the recent [protest negotiations were concluded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391847/388437) to find a new moderator. As we approach two months since the end of those negotiations, I am thrilled to announce our upcoming moderator election.

The hub for this upcoming election is available [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/election/3), with the following schedule in place:

- 10 October: Collection of public questions begins
- 17 October: Nomination Phase begins
- 24 October: Election begins
- 1 November: Election ends

Please be on the lookout for official posts from Stack Exchange staff announcing these landmark events.

Until then, I look forward to continue learning from all of you, and I thank you all for continuing to enrich my experience here.

Comment: Thanks for being a great moderator Richard, and congratulations on your promotion.

Comment: Just curious - I'm going through the list of upcoming elections for each site, and I see that @JNat has posted "official" announcements on most sites' Meta (even those with elections further out than yours). You also mentioned *"be on the lookout for official posts"* here as well, but I don't see one.  Am I missing it, or did this site get missed in the announcements?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Since I'm stepping down, we felt it would be best for the announcement to come from me to give it some added context. JNat will be posting the official announcements beginning 10 October.

Comment: @Richardissteppingdown That makes sense - Thanks.  Best of luck to you moving forward!

Comment: Thank you for the mostly unsung work you've done as a mod here. Good luck in your new post, and please keep on contributing!